# how to acknowledge delete method of morphia (Monogo DB)

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I morphia datastore there i a delete method.
this method is working fine.
but i have doubt about it is 
how we can get the information about the method delete the data successfully.
since the delete() method return WriteResult and in WriteResult which method we have to use so as to we can say data has been delete.

In my case i am using rest web service and in rest web service we have to send http responses like  200,400,500 etc.

while using delete method i should have to get information about the data is really deleted.

how we can achieve this task.

example

```css
int deleteMongoObject(MognoDataObject mongoDataObject) {
      Datastore       datastore=MorphiaDatastoreTrasaction.getDatastore(MognoDataObject.class);
      datastore.delete(mongoDataObject); 
  if(scuccess) {\\ success should be acknowledgment of delete method
      return 200;
      }
      else {
        retrun 403;
      }
    }
```

how we can achieve this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete()` returns a `WriteResult` that shows the number of documents affected.  The `n` field should list the number of documents deleted.

Also as you can see in Morphia `Datastore` implementation default `WriteConcern` is `ACKNOWLEDGED` unless you specified something else for example annotation under your model.

And description of `ACKNOWLEDGED`:

> Write operations that use this write concern will wait for
>   acknowledgement from the primary server before returning. Exceptions
>   are raised for network issues, and server errors.

Comment: Thanks for Answer it is much more helpful it is giving me a value.
Actually i applied workaround for it after calling delete method for id
i again search that id in mongo and if it is not find then i am assuming that data is deleted.

Comment: like that 
datastore.delete(floorPlanSessionDatadelete);
query = datastore.createQuery(FloorPlanSessionData.class);query.field("id").equal(new ObjectId(deleteActiveSessionBean.getStringId()));if(query.get() == null){deleteActiveSessionBean.setMsg("ok");deleteActiveSessionBean.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK);}else{deleteActiveSessionBean.setMsg("Unalbe to delete the data");   deleteActiveSessionBean.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_METHOD_FAILURE);
}